# Restoring a SQL Server 2008 .bak to a SQL Server 2014 server instance via PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, sql-server-2014

I am trying to restore a database to a VM as part of a new VM provisioning process. However, when I try the following command to restore the database:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance . -Database SomeDatabase -BackupFile $latestBackup -ReplaceDatabase
```

It fails with the error:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SomeDatabase.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
At line:27 char:1
+ Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance . -Database SomeDatabase -BackupFile $latestB ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Restore-SqlDatabase], SmoException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.RestoreSqlDatabaseCommand
```

This is confusing, since using SQL Server 2014 has the exact same path, but at `MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER` instead of the `MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER` that the `Restore-SqlDatabase` cmdlet is looking for. A database with the correct name already exists at the `MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER` location as well.

How can I tell the cmdlet to restore it to the right folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't really possible (that I could find) to restore  a database like this. I reverted the VM to use a matching SQL server, and used the following command to restore the database:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "RESTORE DATABASE [SomeDatabase] FROM  DISK = N'C:\$latestBackup' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'SomeDatabase' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SomeDatabase.mdf',  MOVE N'SomeDatabase_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\SomeDatabase.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
```

This was obtained via  SQL Server Management Studio's "Script" functionality, where I set up the restore and exported the equivalent SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by specifying the files locations as objects and passing them to Restore-SQLDatabase with the -RelocateFile parameter

```
$RelocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("MainDB_Data", "c:\MySQLServer\MainDB.mdf")
$RelocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile("MainDB_Log", "c:\MySQLServer\MainDB.ldf")
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "Computer\Instance" -Database "MainDB" -BackupFile "\\mainserver\databasebackup\MainDB.trn" -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog)
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683379%28v=sql.120%29.aspx